# Web Based Story Organization Software for Fiction Writing and Worldbuilding

Tags: windows, android, web-apps, text-editor, collaboration

I'm working on a writing project and I want to know if there is a tool that I can use to organize the work. I need the following features:

- manage story text and link it with character sheets, locations and other world building notes (maps, physics, races, etc).
- See story dates, character events, and historical events on a graphical timeline.
- ability to work collaboratively with another writer

The most important feature is the collaboration. We used to use something called Storybook but it saved projects as binary files. We tried sharing those via Dropbox but if we both made changes then we would cause conflicts and the software didn't have any mechanism for resolving them. Right now we're using Google Docs to record everything because it lets us work on a document at the same time but it does nothing for the organization.

I prefer a solution that is browser based but I'll accept something that runs on Windows 7 or Android.

I don't have any cost requirements at the moment but I would like answers to include the cost for two users. Basically, I need to know if both of us need to buy an app or if we pay for a web solution does it include multiple user logins.

Comment: Not an actual answer, but the fact that no such software currently exists is the reason I've started writing one. Very early in development right now, will be half a year at least until it is useable. But if you are still interested by then, contact me.